# Iterate over nested arrays storing indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need a way to iterate over each element in a `numpy` array of *any shape*, and store its index in a list.

This code produces arrays of general shapes:

```
import numpy as np

# Generate random shape for the array.
sha = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(np.random.randint(1, 10)))
# Random array.
a =np.random.rand(*sha)
```

I need to iterate over each element in `a` and store its index in a list.

The closest I've gotten is by flattening the array:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(a.flatten()):
    print i, elem
```

which allows me to iterate over *every* element in `a` no matter its shape, but I loose the indexes where each element is stored in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools` to create a `product` (Cartesian) of all dimensions

```
from itertools import product
for i in product(*[range(dim) for dim in a.shape]):
    print i, a[i]
```

Comment: All great answers but I'm selecting this one since it does precisely what I asked for. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `numpy.unravel_index`:

```
>>> np.dstack(np.unravel_index(np.arange(a.size), a.shape))
array([[[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 2],
        ...,
        [2, 2, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 0, ..., 1, 1, 2],
        [2, 2, 0, ..., 1, 1, 3]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

`ndindex` generates the multidim index tuples for any array

In fact with this we can generate the nd array of dtype object, and fill it with some function of these indices in one step (ok, 2 steps):

```
shape=(3,4,2)
A = np.empty(shape, dtype=object)
for i in np.ndindex(3,4,2):
    A[i]=i   # or use A[i]=list(i)
```

producing `A`:

```
array([[[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1)],
        [(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1)],
        [(0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1)],
        [(0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1)]],

       [[(1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1)],
        [(1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)],
        [(1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1)],
        [(1, 3, 0), (1, 3, 1)]],

       [[(2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1)],
        [(2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1)],
        [(2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1)],
        [(2, 3, 0), (2, 3, 1)]]], dtype=object)
```

I filled this with tuples rather than lists because the display is clearer.  In

```
array([[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]],
        [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]],
        [[0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1]],
        ....
```

it is hard to distinguish between an array dimension and a list.

With dtype object, the individual elements could be anything.  `np.empty` fills it with `None`.

---

A related data structure would be a flat list of these tuples.  It could still be accessed as though it were nd by using `np.ravel_multi_index`.

```
L1 = [i for i in np.ndindex(shape)]

[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 0),
 ...
 (2, 2, 1),
 (2, 3, 0),
 (2, 3, 1)]
```

Accessed as a simulated deeply nested list:

```
 L1[np.ravel_multi_index(i,shape)]
```

A few access time comparisons:

```
In [137]: %%timeit
for i in np.ndindex(shape):
    x=A[i]
10000 loops, best of 3: 88.3 µs per loop

In [138]: %%timeit
for i in np.ndindex(shape):
    x=L1[np.ravel_multi_index(i,shape)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 227 µs per loop
```

So multidimensional indexing of the array is faster.

```
In [140]: %%timeit
   .....: for i in L1:
   .....:     x=i
1000000 loops, best of 3: 774 ns per loop

In [143]: %%timeit
   .....: for i in A.flat:
    x=i
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 µs per loop
```

But direct iteration over the list is much faster.

---

for the `itertools.produce` iterator:

```
In [163]: %%timeit
   .....: for i in itertools.product(*[range(x) for x in shape]):
    x=A[i]
   .....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.1 µs per loop
```